Error in HtmlWidget || RenderLayoutBuilder class does not support dry layout || RenderBox.debugCannotComputeDryLayout
I am receiving JSON data in html format in API response, and I have to show this in screen. I am using HTMLWidget by plugin but there is an issue. I don't want to wrap this in alert box an show dialog this is an recording an I have to just show this on screen.
Error
 I/flutter ( 5236): Ignored _performLayoutDry error: The _RenderLayoutBuilder class does not support dry layout.
    I/flutter ( 5236): Calculating the dry layout would require running the layout callback speculatively, which might mutate the live render object tree.
    I/flutter ( 5236): #0      RenderBox.debugCannotComputeDryLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1938:11)

Code
Padding(
  padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
  child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: _activityData?.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var _activityList = _activityData?[index];
        return  HtmlWidget(
                _activityList?.message?.toString() ?? "",
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: FontSizes.normalFontSize),
              );

Code

Output

Error

